# UIBarButtonItems wont show in navigationBar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

I've created a navigationBar in my view which is suppose to hold 2 buttons left and right. The problem is whatever i do it wont show the buttons/views. How am i suppose to do this? here is my code so far.

[image]

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [ NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Aerovias Brasil NF", size: 30)!,  NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]

    navTitleView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 44))
    titleLabel.text = "SHOPOP"
    navTitleView?.addSubview(titleLabel)
    self.navigationItem.titleView?.addSubview(navTitleView!)

    navigationHeight = UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame.height+self.navigationController!.navigationBar.bounds.height

    searchBar = UISearchBar(frame: CGRectZero)
    searchBarWrapper = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 100, self.navigationController!.navigationBar.bounds.size.width, self.navigationHeight!))
    var buttonSearchBar:UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: searchBar!)
    var cancelButton:UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: nil, action: nil)
    searchBarWrapper?.topItem?.leftBarButtonItem = buttonSearchBar
    searchBarWrapper?.topItem?.rightBarButtonItem = cancelButton

    self.navigationController?.view.addSubview(searchBarWrapper!)


}


@IBAction func showSearchBar(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {


    searchBar?.becomeFirstResponder()
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25,  animations: {
        // Optional chaining may return nil
        self.searchBarWrapper!.center = CGPointMake(self.navigationController!.view.center.x, self.navigationHeight!/2)


        // return
        }, completion: {
            finished in
            println("Basket doors opened!")
    })

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func hideSearchBar(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25,  animations: {
        // Optional chaining may return nil
        self.searchBarWrapper!.center = CGPointMake(self.navigationController!.view.center.x, -self.navigationHeight!/2)

        self.searchBar?.resignFirstResponder()

        // return
        }, completion: {
            finished in
            println("Basket doors opened!")
    })
```

Comment: Try my answer below for just getting some basic buttons showing in your navigation controller. Then experiment with putting custom views inside of a UIBarButtonItem. I'm going to instinctively say that stuffing a UISearchBar inside of UIBarButtonItem is probably the wrong way to go about things.

Comment: i do not need it in a navigationController but in uinavigationBar not connected to uinavigationcontroller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the changes to your question you should look into the [UISearchController class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchController/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UISearchController). A cursory glance at the documentation leads me to believe that after you configure it properly you can push it onto the view controller stack and it will behave like you want.

---

**Old answer:**

While I'm not sure about wrapping a UISearchBar inside of a UIBarButtonItem I can say with certainty that this is the wrong way to go about adding a UINavigationBar to a UINavigationController:

```
self.navigationController?.view.addSubview(searchBarWrapper!)
```

The right way to go about providing items for the navigation bar is to override UIViewController's `navigationItem` property and return a customized `UINavigationItem` instance. This way when you push and pop view controllers off of the UINavigationController's stack the navigation bar will be updated automatically.

This is an example from a UIViewController subclass in one of my projects.

```
private var customNavigationItem = UINavigationItem(title:nil);

override var navigationItem:UINavigationItem
{
    get
    {
        customNavigationItem.title = self.title;
        customNavigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem:.Cancel,
            target:self, action:"dismissForm:");
        customNavigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem:.Save,
            target:self, action:"saveForm:");

        return customNavigationItem;
    }
}
```

Doing this will ensure that all of the "free" functionality that UINavigationController provides works as intended. **Messing with UINavigationController's view is generally a bad idea.**

Comment: I'm trying to make a UINavigationBar animate down when a UIBarButtonItem from self.navigationController.navigationBar is pressed. This is working fine, but i need searchBar in it

Comment: i've added code above. I'm trying to animate a new navigationBar down from the top as in the ios calender app. I've done that but i have a hard time adding buttons to the new navigationBar

Comment: saved my time. btw why can't I link to uiviewcontrollernavitem directly from xib and have to do this: @IBOutlet weak var navItem: UINavigationItem!
 override var navigationItem:UINavigationItem
  {
  get
  {
   return self.navItem
  }
 } is that because the property is exposed on the uiviewcontroller?